# Coefficients should be Integers: sympy diophantine equations

Tags: python, sympy

I have a polynomial (generated from the characteristic polynomial of a matrix) and I'd like to solve for the integer solutions

```
import sympy
from sympy.solvers.diophantine import diop_linear

M = sympy.Matrix([[0,1,1],[1,0,1],[1,1,0]])
p = M.charpoly()
```

This polynomial clearly factors into integer roots:

```
print p.factor()
# (_lambda - 2)*(_lambda + 1)**2
```

The input polynomial however, is expected to be an integer coefficient type when using [`diop_linear(p)`](http://docs.sympy.org/latest/modules/solvers/diophantine.html#sympy.solvers.diophantine.diop_linear). I'm not sure how to do this using sympy 0.75, despite looking through the docs. The traceback is:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 8, in <module>
    diop_linear(p)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/diophantine.py", line 365, in diop_linear
    var, coeff, diop_type = classify_diop(eq)
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/sympy/solvers/diophantine.py", line 232, in classify_diop
    raise TypeError("Coefficients should be Integers")
TypeError: Coefficients should be Integers
```

Comment: Bookmarked - You've got me interested!

Answer (score 1):

That error message is clearly incorrect. The problem is that `diop_linear` only works for linear diophantine equations (which for single variable equations are not that interesting). If you just want to solve a single variable equation, just use `solve`.

Comment: I want to solve over the field of integers, in that if the polynomial has non-integer roots I want no solution to be returned. So yes, I'm looking _exactly_ for the "not interesting" case of a single variable linear Diophantine equation. Using solve and getting a floating point fails sometimes - and sympy seems to choke on large polynomials of order 20 or so. Is there a way to restrict the solution space to Z?

Comment: Wrong error is due to the fact that `classify_diop` which is called by `diop_linear` to ensure that equation is a linear one fails with the `Poly` object. Use `diophantine` with `p.factor()` as the equation so you can avoid this. It also filters integer roots from the roots of the Polynomial. Don't use `diop_linear` or any other equation-type specific function if you don't know for sure what the equation type is. I recommend you always use `diophantine` to solve any diophantine equation with SymPy.

Comment: I think a fairly efficient way to get only integer roots would be to use RootOf, which avoids computing fairly complex radical forms of roots.